# Unable to use any of the Opencv drawing operations in android

Tags: android, opencv

```
Point p1 = new Point(), p2 = new Point();
p1.x = (double)i;
p1.y = (double)j;
p2.x = (double)i;
p2.y = (double)k+1;
Imgproc.line(imgMat, p1, p2, new Scalar(255,0,0));
```

In this Code, the line function does not seems to work and it gives me an     error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.line_2:(JDDDDDDDD)V
```

Can someone help me??
Edit: I can't use other drawing functions like rectangle, ellipse and arrowed line also. Every functions gives me the same error

Comment: which opencv version are you using ? for 2.4, the drawing stuff is in Core, for 3.0 in Imgproc.

Comment: Its 3.0.0, The stuff is in Imgproc. But somehow it can't find the native method for drawing a line (C++ code). Also I found out that the Openv Manager currently in use is for 2.4.9. Can this be a problem?

Comment: Hi! were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same thing and can't think a way out at all :(. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and i fix it now.I import **opencv3.0** into my android studio but i load **opencv2.4.11** in code.Change:

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, getApplicationContext(), mLoaderCallback);
```

to:

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, getApplicationContext(), mLoaderCallback);
```

Hope it works for you,good luck!